# Docker hangs during build when I try to start a tomcat server

Tags: windows, docker

I'm using Windows containers and the microsoft/nanoserver as my base. I'm trying to start up a Tomcat server during the build, but when I do so the build hangs and all I can is cancel it. Unfortunately I have to start the server so it will deploy a war file so that I can then stop the server and alter its configuration. I know I can just run the image, make my changes, and then commit but this seems like cheating. The only thing I can think of is that the startup / catalina script is writing to stdout, but I've tried redirecting to null and it still hangs. Any ideas out there for me to try?

Dockerfile excerpt:

```
RUN powershell start-process -FilePath .\startup.bat -ArgumentList "/c" -NoNewWindow -RedirectStandardOutput Out-Null
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you can't have a java process running on the image during the build; I was able to fix this by using Start-Sleep to wait for about a minute and then kill any java process running on the machine. The build proceeded after that.